# Use cases and explainig for "Mahlzeit"

Tags: expression

I have seen that people use the expression "Mahlzeit" before eating, but I also have heard them use in another occasions, even though I did not understand at the time why.

- What are the use cases for this expression?
- Is there any generic translation that works for every occasion?
- What is the reason for writing it like that? "mal" seems to be a modal particle, with no special meaning, but "Zeit" meant just "time". Not sure what it has to do with "eating".

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, I got the spelling wrong. It is "mahlzeit", not "mal zeit". I have updated it in the question.

Comment: It's quite common to say in many companies just instead of _hallo_. The correct spelling is _Mahlzeit_ BTW.

Comment: There is a second - ironic - meaning as in _Nächste Woche bekommen wir wieder neue Programme auf die Rechner. - Na dann Prost Mahlzeit und viel Spaß damit!_ According to dict.cc the meaning is '_Good luck, fat chance (of that)!_'.

Comment: Some say it's short (secularized) for the blessing `Gesegnete Mahlzeit`.

Comment: Uh... folks, answers, please, not [answers in comments](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment)! (Unless you see the question as duplicate, which means VTC.)

Comment: _@Enrique_ Also note that there's usage of _mal Zeit_ like in _"Hast Du mal (kurz) Zeit?"_ Which means something completely different.

Comment: Zeit ist Zeit.
Ist Einheit für Gemütlichkeit.
Wäre Gemütlichkeit
dreitausendsechshundert
Sekunden in Zeit,
für wieviel Gemütlichkeit
bliebe dann Zeit?

Zeit plus Zeit ist mehr Zeit.
Brot plus Zeit ist Brotzeit.
Zeit mal Zeit ist Mahlzeit.

Der Maikäfer dreht
um den Tisch eine Runde,
Du weißt nicht das Jahr,
Du kennst nicht die Stunde.

Die Kastanie im Biergarten blüht,
freue Dich,
Du bist auf erdbebensicherem Gebiet.

Das ist die Wurzel aus Zeit.
Das ist per Saldo - Gemütlichkeit.

Comment: @Stephie I admire your optimism with this.

Comment: @LangLangC: Bist Du der Urheber oder Gerhard Polt?

Comment: @Stephie: Wieso sollten Antworten als Kommentar in Ordnung sein, wenn die Frage ein Duplikat ist? Damit derjenige sich nicht die Mühe machen muss, dort die Antworten nachzulesen und evtl. zu bewerten?

Comment: "but I also have heard them use in another occasions, even though I did not understand at the time why." But now you understand? And what was that occasion?

Comment: @userunknown öh... sind sie nicht? Man sollte entweder antworten (legitime Fragen) oder alternativ close-voten (als Duplikate oder wegen anderem Grund). Kommentare sind für Rückfragen oder Anmerkungen. Oder gelegentlich den einen oder anderen blöden Spruch >.<  Sorry, falls ich es zu ungenau formuliert habe. Ich habe selbst nicht VTC, weil zwar „Mahlzeit“ zum Essen ein dupe, „mal Zeit“ oder „(Prost) Mahlzeit“ in anderem Kontext keiner ist („other occasions“).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Germans often shorten welcome formula by omitting the "Guten" or "Schönen". For example the following ones turn this way:

- "(Ich wünsche eine) Schöne/Gute Mahlzeit!" => "Mahlzeit!" (Note: It does not work with "Guten
  Appetit!")
- "Guten Morgen!" => "Morgen!" ("Morjen" as heavy
  dialect)
- "Guten Abend!" => "N'Abend!" ("Namd!" as heavy reduction)
- "Guten Tag!" => "Tag!" ("Tach!" as dialect)

---

Your mentioned word "Mal zeit" is a typo. You have heard "Mahlzeit" (engl. "meal").

Comment: Note: https://german.stackexchange.com/users/28897/%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96

Comment: The insistence on OP making  typo is unfounded. It is about *reading* it, prolly in a mail or text. Haste mal Zeit die Frage zu lesen, oder vielleicht irgendwann mal Zeit was zu essen?

Comment: Far more often, by design, omitting all but "Gudn". That applies to "Gudn Hunga" as well. Much more than to the utterly nonexistent "Gute Mahlzeit!"?

Comment: *Moin* ist nicht kurz für *Guten morgen*, sondern das plattdeutsche Wort für *schön*, und damit kurz für *Schönen guten Tag*. Das spielt zwar sprachgeschichtlich hier keine Rolle, erklärt aber, warum man *Moin* den ganzen Tag über sagt, nicht nur morgens.

Comment: @LangLangC I did type it incorrectly. I did mean "mahlzeit". I have corrected it in the question.

Comment: @Philipp. Die Etymologie von "moin" ist umstritten. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moin

Comment: "Moin" habe ich rausgenommen. Ich hoffe, jetzt hört das Downgevote aber auch auf... :)

Comment: War kein downvote von mir ;-)